# I'm trying to design a simple Ruby calculator and I'm getting an error

Tags: ruby, calculator

So I've been messing around with Ruby for the first time after finishing the codecademy course up to "Object Oriented Programming, Part I" and I decided to start making a calculator.  For some reason though, I get this error:

```
calc.rb:13:in `addition': undefined local variable or method `user_input' for main:Object (NameError)
  from calc.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

I'm confused why it doesn't see my "user_input" array.  Is it out of the scope of the method?  Did I initialize it wrong?

Here's the code so you can see for yourself, it's obviously nothing sophisticated and it's not finished.  I'm just trying to test for addition right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

user_input = Array.new

puts "Would you like to [a]dd, [s]ubtract, [m]ultiply, or [d]ivide? "

type_of_math = gets.chomp

def addition
  operator = :+
  puts "Please enter the numbers you want to add (enter \"=\" to stop adding numbers): "
  until gets.chomp == "="
    user_input << gets.chomp.to_i
  end
  sum = user_input.inject(operator)
  return sum
end

case type_of_math
when "a"
  addition
when "s"
  puts "Test for subtraction"
when "m"
  puts "Test for multiplication"
when "d"
  puts "Test for division"
else
  puts "Wrong"
end
```

Comment: " Is it out of the scope of the method?" Yes.

Comment: @Vanram note that `until gets.chomp == "="` and  `user_input << gets.chomp.to_i` will both read a line. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Stefan How would you suggest fixing this?

Comment: You have to store the result in a variable, just like `type_of_math`

Comment: @Stefan This fixed one problem but, now even with it stored in a variable it just keeps asking for input and won't end when I enter "="

Comment: @Vanram code in comments is really hard to read. Why don't you post a separate question? Something like _"How do I read user input into an array until a delimiter is entered?"_.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this untested variation on your code. It's more idiomatic:

```
def addition
  user_input = []
  puts 'Please enter the numbers you want to add (enter "=" to stop adding numbers): '
  loop do
    input = gets.chomp
    break if input == '='
    user_input << input
  end
  user_input.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

Notice that it puts `user_input` into the method. It also uses the normal `[]` direct assignment of an empty array to initialize it. Rather than `chomp.to_i` each value as it's entered it waits to do that until after the loop exits.

Instead of `while` loops, consider using `loop do`. They tend to be more easily seen when scanning code.

Also notice there's no `return` at the end of the method. Ruby automatically returns the last value seen.